# mongo DB - All nodes secondary

Tags: mongodb

All of the nodes in our cluster are "secondary" and no node is stepping up as "primary".

How do I force a node to become primary?

===SOLUTION===
We had 4 nodes in our replica set, when we are supposed to only have an odd number of nodes.

1. Remove a node so you have an odd number of nodes

   - rs.config()

   Edit the list of servers in notepad/textpad removing one of the servers

   - config = POST_MODIFIED_LIST_HERE
   - rs.reconfig(config, {force:true})
2. Stop the mongodb service 'mongod' on all nodes, and bring them back up
3. Done

If this doesn't fix it, try adding a priority to one of the nodes.

Comment: please post the state of the replica set - rs.status() for example - to show if they are recovering, unreachable, which has the latest timestamp etc. - it's hard to suggest what to try without some detail

Comment: thanks mate. that's a good question/answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following instructions available at MongoDB's website:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Forcing+a+Member+to+be+Primary

Comment: this was part of the solution, the other part as I mentioned in my edited question above, was that we accidentally had an even number of nodes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an even number of nodes, one answer is to remove one. Another answer can be to add an arbiter, which doesn't have a copy of the data but participates in the cluster purely for voting and breaks ties. This way you get odd vote numbers and guaranteed elections, but the availability/capacity of four nodes.